# get latex variable/definition from file

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex

So we have a file which has mappings like:

one/two/one.tex 27/11/85
some/other/two.tex 27/03/89

I would like all our documents to reference this file and pull out the appropriate date. For example, for one.tex, it would display 27/11/85

Any suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package.

You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.